# Can't pull objects Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Pretty new to JS, everything I've read on objects doesn't explain how to pull the object back out, for instance, here's a quick example:

```
$('#ABtn').click({
    function(){
        runAlert({
            message: "hello world"
        });
    }
});

function runAlert(parameters){
    alert(parameters.message);
}
```

when it runs "runAlert()", how do I pull the object "message" as a variable and use it to display an alert of "hello world"? I've googled and read, but I just can't seem to grasp it. I made a fiddle, if someone could show me how to do it so I can understand it, that'd be awesome: http://jsfiddle.net/WEZ9V/4/

Comment: Please check your JavaScript console for errors before posting (or if the console errors don't help you, at least include them in your post.)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know I was getting any, I thought jsfiddle would should you errors.

Comment: No, jsfiddle just runs what you give it, you have to check your browser's console to see the errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had a syntax error:

```
$('#ABtn').click({
    //           ^--------this { should not be there.
    function(){
        runAlert({
            message: "hello world"
        });
    });

function runAlert(parameters){
    alert(parameters.message);
}
```

Once that's removed, it works fine: [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WEZ9V/5/).

Incidentally, had you looked at the browser's JavaScript, or error, console (<kbd>F12</kbd> in most browsers) the error 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (` would have drawn your attention to the situation. Particularly in JS Fiddle, where clicking the <kbd>JS Hint</kbd> button will highlight the lines where it perceives errors to be (always check the line prior to the *first* error).

Comment: Oops, works great, exactly what I was trying to do! Thanks so much! It won't let me accept it for 9 minutes, see you in 9!

Answer (score 1):

What you've done is fine, you just have a syntax error:

```
$('#ABtn').click(function(){
        runAlert({
            message: "hello world"
        });
    }
);

function runAlert(parameters){
    alert(parameters.message);
}
```

***Live Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/rt3J2/*

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in your source (**always check the JavaScript console for errors** when troubleshooting scripts!) `click` is a function, so you should have parens, not curly braces:

```
$('#ABtn').click(
    function(){
        runAlert({
            message: "hello world"
        });
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error, you're using curly braces where you should have used parens.

```
   $('#ABtn').click( //use parens here
    function(){

        runAlert({
            message: "hello"
        });
    }
); // and here

function runAlert(parameters){
    alert(parameters.message);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First off you have the syntax wrong for specifying a function for click.  It needs to be of the form

```
$('#ABtn').click(function(){
    your code
});
```

This makes it easier to see what you have done wrong.  What you need is

```
$('#ABtn').click(function(){
    runAlert({message:"hello"});
});
function runAlert(parameters){
    alert(parameters.message);
}
```

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uq8Vt/1/